# why can't i import ssh2-python module

Tags: python, import, module, spyder, ssh2

from ssh2 import Session
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\saluc\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_20116\996579583.py", line 1, in 
from ssh2 import Session

### ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ssh2'

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install ssh2-python

Requirement already satisfied: ssh2-python in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.0)

### (base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c conda-forge ssh2-python

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- ssh2-python

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>

---

(base) c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>

(base) c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>dir | findstr ssh2

26.11.2022  00:18              ssh2

26.11.2022  00:18              ssh2_python-1.0.0.dist-info

(base) c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages>